# Java observables in WPF?

Tags: java, c#, wpf, mvvm

I am a .Net developer and recently spoke with a buddy of mine who is a Java dev.

I was explaining about WPF MVVM and how, if you want a property updated in a view, you must not only databind it but also trigger the "OnPropertyChanged" event handler.

He was shocked there aren't ready wrappers for that. For example he told me there is "Observable String" in Java, which automatically knows to update the value in the view if it is changed in the backend.

(I know about observable collections but even they must expicitly be given an event handler to call when the collection is changed)

He claims these "observables" in Java don't need any special setup and don't need to be given event handlers to call, by default they update the view after only being declared/initialized.

Is there something like this in WPF MVVM, have I been doing it wrong or is it not like this in Java, at all?

Comment: Plenty of frameworks do that https://www.reactiveui.net/

Comment: Your buddy used the `RxJava`, it is implemented in multiple languages. You can learn it in http://reactivex.io/languages.html

Comment: "*observable collections but even they must expicitly be given an event handler to call when the collection is changed*" - that is a misconception. You just use an ObservableCollection in place of some other other List type. A UI element with a property bound to such a collection will automatically register an event handler. You don't need to do anything manually.

Comment: @Clemens, oh, I thought we need to provide a handler for "CollectionChanged" event.

Answer (score 0):

The way WPF "automatically knows" when to update a target property is when the source object implements the `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface and raises the `PropertyChanged` event for this property. That's how the binding engine is implemented.

The framework doesn't subscribe to some other "observables" (whatever that means in this case).

So you have not done things wrong if you have implemented `INotifyPropertyChanged` and raised the `PropertyChanged` event in your view models.